# Android: dialog background with bitmap, round corners with border

Tags: android, layout, background, dialog

In a dialog, I would like it to be having a background, with 3dp green round corner border. I have implemented the below:

### Dialog

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_round_corners_image"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" >
    .....
</RelativeLayout>
```

### layout_round_corners_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/strip1">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/green" />

            <corners android:radius="35px" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

## Question:

The dialog now is not showing any image (strip1), just having a black (blank) background with 3dp green round corner border.

How could the image be the background of the dialog with its corners adjusted within the green round corner border?

Thanks!!

Comment: write the code for the Main Actvity how you implemented the dialog

Comment: Refere Stack Overflow Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566678/dialog-with-custom-view-background

Answer (score 1):

It works by creating a new class, coding as follows:

### New Class:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

      public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
           super(context);
      }

      public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
      }

      public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      }


      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           int radius = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.corner_radius); // angle of round corners
           Path clipPath = new Path();
           RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
           clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
           canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
           super.onDraw(canvas);
       }
    }
```

### and then in layout.xml, replace ImageView by RoundedImageView:

```
    <com.example.abc.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgd_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp2"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/strip1" />
```